# Dual boot with Windows 11 pre-installed on new laptop asks for Bitlocker Key

Tags: dual-boot, windows, secure-boot

I recently purchased a new laptop--HP Pavilion 15 eh1097nr--that came with Windows 11 pre-installed on a 512GB SSD.  I would like to install Ubuntu along side Windows and dual boot.

I ran the live USB for 21.10, and it did boot, but couldn't find the network card.  I hadn't prepared any partitions yet, and wouldn't want to do an install until I figured out the network card issue (Realtek RTL8852AE--I need to download the drivers, I now know), so I shutdown, removed the USB drive, and booted the laptop back up.  It asked for my BitLocker Key.

I know this is related to TPM, Secure Boot and BitLocker. I tried turning off Secure Boot, booting into Ubuntu, then back into Windows, but it still asked for the key. I don't want to turn off BitLocker until I've tried all other possibilities.

So I searched for an answer, and came across a post that says [I need to use the Windows Boot Loader](https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/12/05/on-dual-booting-tpm-linux-windows-and-bitlocker/). As I haven't installed Ubuntu yet, I skipped ahead to the part where it says

> ...right click on the System Reserved partition and select "Change Drive Letter and Paths...". Select "Add...", and then choose "Assign the following drive letter:" with your choice of drive letter.

When I right click on the System Reserved partition, there is no option to assign a drive letter.  There is for my main Windows partition, but not for my System Reserved.

So, I'm kind of stuck.  Is there any way to dual boot Linux and Windows 11 on a computer that came with Windows 11, has TPM (of course) and BitLocker?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a Windows question than an Ubuntu question. BitLocker is proprietary disk encryption from Microsoft for Windows.  You need to create enough unpartitioned free space in order to install Ubuntu in dual boot configuration.  You will need to consult with Windows documentation and support in order to do this.  Perhaps ask on SuperUser.  FYI drive letters are a Windows convention and totally irrelevant to Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: While I agree with your assessment, in part, that it's a Windows question, it's also an Ubuntu/Linux question in that it involves setting up Ubuntu to dual boot.  The solution may lie in how Ubuntu/Linux is installed or configured. For instance, somewhere in there is mentioned a TPM friendly version of grub.  Installing and configuring that would not be a Windows issue.

Ignore the Windows configuration part of it for now.  Is there anyway to configure Ubuntu so that dual booting between Ubuntu and Windows doesn't cause this issue?

Comment: There is nothing you can do in Ubuntu to solve this problem. The only thing that is relevant to Ubuntu at this point is what I wrote above- you need to make **unpartitioned free space**. You can't use Ubuntu to do this.  This is **especially** true because the drive is currently encrypted using proprietary Microsoft software. You need to consult Windows documentation or support in order to shrink your Windows partition so that you can free up enough unpartitioned free space. You'll have to do this from within Windows.